# X: Beyond the Frontier and Xbox 360 Controller

Tags: controllers, x-beyond-the-frontier

A few years ago, I got a software collection with the full version of X BtF on it. At this time I didn't really understood the game, but yesterday I really wanted to give it a try again.

I remember playing it with my Xbox Controller for Windows, which was way more fun than playing it with the keyboard. As I started it again today, the controller wouldnt work in the main menu (I assume it wont work ingame either).
I wanted to reinstall it, but the DVD of the software collection is missing.

Does anyone know what I might try to get it working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought it hasn't worked in the main menu it works ingame. I am still not able to configure it correctly for use in main menu or to select messages, but you can control the ship.